# Tradingview pine script indicator: Time frame condition -> plot shape on all time frames

Tags: pine-script

I'm very new to pine script, don't have any experience.
I'm trying to create a condition ("bull") that is tied to a specific time frame (240).
The entire idea is that when all 3 conditions are met (price crosses up EMA1 and closes above EMA and time frame is 240) then plot a shape below the bar.
Here's the snippet I have so far.

```
bull = ta.crossover(close, EMA1) and close > EMA2 and timeframe.period == "240"
plotshape(bull, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(44, 123, 118), size = size.tiny)
```

Now this works well on the 4h (240) time frame, but not on any other TF. I'd like to see the plotted shape on all time frames (but tied to the 4h).

I'm guessing this is a multi time frame issue, but as I said before, I'm new to this.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
bull = ta.crossover(close, EMA1) and close > EMA2 and timeframe.period == "240"

req_bull=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '', bull,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)
plotshape(req_bull, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(44, 123, 118), size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it doesn't resolve the issue. The shape is still plotted only below the 240min bar.
I'm wondering if there's maybe a logic issue. I mean if the condition is created on the 240 bar - how can the plot be displayed on a 60min bar, and which one of the 4 60min bars? Maybe that's a problem that can't be resolved?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the request.security function to get all of the values from the 240 chart. This will only work on a 240 or lower time frame though

Here's an example:

```
ema1 = request.security(syminfo.ticker, '240', ta.ema(close,5))
close240 = request.security(syminfo.ticker, '240', close)
bull = ta.crossover(close240, ema1) and close240 > ema1
plotshape(bull, 'bull', style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar)
```

[image: AAPL 60 min chart with the example code]